# ng2-select componant use multiple in one page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I want to use the two ng2-select componant  in my modal 
[enter link description here](https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/)

I don't konw how to catch the value selected of each one there no explaination about using + than one select.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

It tells you how to do it right on the page you linked:

```
(selected)="selected($event)"
```

You could use a simple version of it like so:

```html
<ng-select [items]="itemsState"
           (selected)="selectedState($event)"
           placeholder="No state selected">
</ng-select>
<ng-select [items]="itemsCity"
           (selected)="selectedCity($event)"
           placeholder="No city selected">
</ng-select>
```

And in your code you have different methods for selection:

```ts
selectedState($event) {
    // filter itemsCity somehow or whatever you want
    console.log($event.text);
}

selectedCity($event) {
    console.log($event.text);
}
```